# CakePHP display data of two tables in one index.ctp

Tags: cakephp

I have the following code in my companies/index.ctp :

```
<div class="companies index">
    <h2><?php echo __('Company Details'); ?></h2>
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
            <th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('Id'); ?></th>
            <th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('Company Name'); ?></th>
            <th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('ABN'); ?></th>
            <th><?php echo "Billing Address"; ?>
            <?php echo $this->Paginator->sort(''); ?>
            <?php echo $this->Paginator->sort(''); ?>
            <?php echo $this->Paginator->sort(''); ?>
            <?php echo $this->Paginator->sort(''); ?></th>
            <th><?php echo "Shipping Address"; ?>
            <?php echo $this->Paginator->sort(''); ?>
            <?php echo $this->Paginator->sort(''); ?>
            <?php echo $this->Paginator->sort(''); ?>
            <?php echo $this->Paginator->sort(''); ?></th>
            <th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('Phone'); ?></th>
            <th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('Email'); ?></th>
            <th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('Fax'); ?></th>
            <th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('Website'); ?></th>
            <th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('Description'); ?></th>
            <th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('License Number'); ?></th>
            <th class="actions"><?php echo __(''); ?></th>
    </tr>
    <?php foreach ($companies as $company): ?>

    <tr>
        <td><?php echo h($company['Company']['id']); ?>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><?php echo h($company['Company']['company_name']); ?>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><?php echo h($company['Company']['ABN']); ?>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><?php echo h($company['CompaniesBillingAddress']['company_street_address']); ?>&nbsp;
        <?php echo h($company['CompaniesBillingAddress']['company_suburb']); ?>&nbsp;
      <?php echo h($company['CompaniesBillingAddress']['company_state']); ?>&nbsp;
        <?php echo h($company['CompaniesBillingAddress']['company_postcode']); ?>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><?php echo h($company['Company']['company_street_address']); ?>&nbsp;
        <?php echo h($company['Company']['company_suburb']); ?>&nbsp;
        <?php echo h($company['Company']['company_state']); ?>&nbsp;
        <?php echo h($company['Company']['company_postcode']); ?>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><?php echo h($company['Company']['company_phone']); ?>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><?php echo h($company['Company']['company_email']); ?>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><?php echo h($company['Company']['company_fax']); ?>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><?php echo h($company['Company']['company_website']); ?>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><?php echo h($company['Company']['company_description']); ?>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><?php echo h($company['Company']['license_number']); ?>&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="actions">

            <?php echo $this->Html->link(__('View'), array('action' => 'view', $company['Company']['id'])); ?>
            </td>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
    </table>
```

companiesController:

public $components = array('Paginator');

```
public function index() {
    $this->Company->recursive = 0;
    $this->set('companies', $this->Paginator->paginate());
}
```

//some code
}

companiesBillingAddressController

```
public $components = array('Paginator');

    public function index() {
        $this->CompaniesBillingAddress->recursive = 0;
        $this->set('companiesBillingAddresses', $this->Paginator->paginate());
    }}
```

CompaniesBillingAddress table belongs to Companies table. I want the data in the companiesBillingAddress table to be displayed in the companies/index.ctp. 
I keep getting an error saying "Undefined index: CompaniesBillingAddress [APP\View\Companies\index.ctp, line 36". Can someone help me please?

Comment: did u attach the containable behavior??

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->Company->recursive = 1;
```

in your companiesController should do the job. Great approach in cases like "Undefined index" is to debug your array in the view. If you don't find the data you expect, take a look in your controller. in this case the fault is your disabled recursion.

Besides, I would not recommend the use of recursion but rather the [containable behaviour](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html).
So setting recursion to 0 is actually a good way.

Comment: changing companiesController to $this-> Company-> recursive =1; did not fix the problem. I get the same error still. Is there anything else i need to change? and if I used containable behavior and make recursive = 0 then what else should I add in the code?